# Pimple - extend object definition

Tags: php, dependency-injection, pimple

I'm rebuilding my current code and I'm trying to do it with dependency injection. I've downloaded Pimple and in one file, I'm trying to create a few examples for myself. In the documentation I came to method extend, but I'm not able to make it work. For test I have created simple class:

```
class ExtendClass
{
  private $extend = 'false';
    
  public function extendIt()
  {
    $this->extend = 'true';
  }
}
```

I've created simple object, **$DI** is instance of Pimple\Container:

```
$DI['extend'] = function( $c )
{
    return new ExtendClass();
};
```

I've tried to extend it with this:

```
$DI->extend( 'extend', function( $extend, $c )
{
    $extend->extendIt();
    return $extend;
} );
```

But it gave me this error:

> Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Identifier
> "extend" does not contain an object definition.

So i looked to the container nad found out, that I need to add method __invoke into my class, so i added it and make this method to return instance:

```
class ExtendClass
{
    private $extend = 'false';

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function extendIt()
    {
        $this->extend = 'true';
    }
}
```

but after that I get this error:

> RuntimeException: Cannot override frozen service "extend".

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you running $DI->extend( 'extend', function( $extend, $c ) in the setUp method of PHPUnit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extends service like this:

```
$DI->extend( 'extend', function($app)
{
    $app['extend']->extendIt();
    return $app['extend'];
} );
```